# Cant make meteor account-password to work with meteor-angular2

Tags: meteor, angular, angular-meteor, angular2-meteor

i used the angular2 whatsapp clone to start a project.

https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup

This project uses SMS auth but i want a normal user password account, but i cant make it work. It always says that Account.createUser doest not exists. When i debug i can see that accounts-pasword has not been imported, even after adding using atmosphere. (meteor add..)

Here is the repo forked from whatsapp clone:

- https://github.com/mariohmol/ionic2-meteor-messenger

Please, help.. i just need to make a normal login.. and is so hard to get it working.

Here is some update:

- https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/issues/389#issuecomment-247853526

bests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure it out, here is repo with the explanation:

- https://github.com/mariohmol/ionic2-meteor-messenger-password

Basicly you will need another module that is not on documentation an was quite hard to find to be honest.

The module is:

- https://github.com/idanwe/accounts-password-client-side/